# How to create a custom check box by inflating a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a custom check box view, by inflating a layout, I want to manipulate the views in the layout based on the check box status (checked/unchecked), also I want to add custom xml attributes for that view.

Answer (score 0):

take a look on [Creating a View Class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) and [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)